# Getting "Invalid or expired token" from tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I opened a developer account on twitter yesterday and got approved.
I'm trying to learn how to work with tweepy but after inserting my API credentials I keep getting the following error when running this code (I scrambled my credentials).
I tripled checked that the credentials I entered are correct.
Any suggestions?

```
import tweepy


consumer_key = "AkFM0Lo9..." #API KEY
consumer_secret = "f5Txptjr8DePG34JOx..." #API key secret:
access_token = "hYt1Mwky0zGfRUqPKu8Lb..." #Access token:
access_token_secret = "MxzI4FD5HAX4GlXadjlc2..." #Access token secret:
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)




auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

api.lookup_users(['hamid', 'python'])
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-33-bf513b9e8573>", line 20, in <module>
    api.lookup_users(['hamid', 'python'])

  File "C:\Users\yaniv_cfrphva\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 386, in lookup_users
    return bind_api(

  File "C:\Users\yaniv_cfrphva\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 252, in _call
    return method.execute()

  File "C:\Users\yaniv_cfrphva\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 234, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)

TweepError: [{'code': 17, 'message': 'No user matches for specified terms.'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you posted doesn't seem to match the title of your post. If there was a problem with your credentials I would expect it to error at line 10.

You also do not need these lines 15-18 (you already set the credentials once, so these are redundant)

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

To fix your issue, try:

```
users=api.lookup_users("hamid","python")
print(users)
```